# How to see how many memory locations are full in Array

Tags: java, arrays

Need help with a program I'm doing. So I allocated my array, for example:

```
hand = new PlayingCard[5]; //5 Cards in a hand
```

I set the info for `hand[0]` and `hand[1]`,

```
hand[0] = deck.dealACard(); 
hand[1] = newDeck.dealACard();
```

My question is, when I try to figure out how many
cards are currently in hand[ ] I get "5" instead of "2".

```
numCards = hand.length;
```

What do I need to do to get numCards to equal "2" right now?

Comment: Use a List instead of array.

Comment: ... and use `size()` to see how many there are. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can easily use:

```
public static int countNonNullElements(Object[] array) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] != null) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

However, normally it's a better idea to use a `List<E>` instead (e.g. `ArrayList<E>`) to represent a collection with a varying size.

Comment: is countNonNullElements a method?? I need to set numCards to represent the number of cards in the hand array somehow.

Comment: @LClarke27: Yes, it's a method. You'd call that method, passing in the reference to your array. Have you learned about calling methods yet?

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through:

```
int count = 0
for (PlayingCard c : hand) {
    if (c != null) count ++
}
//count is now how many cards there are
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either implementa method that iterates thought the entire array to see if there are elements in the indexes, or you can keep a local variable with the number, and you control it by adding and removing.

If it is at all possible, I prefer the 2nd one. It gives you an answer in constant time for the price of 1 local variable, instead of linear time, as would be the 1st solution

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an **array** of `PlayingCard` which once intialized would have fixed size i.e `5` in your case..

You can use `List`

```
List<PlayingCard> playingCardList=new ArrayList();
playingCardList.add(new PlayingCard());
playingCardList.add(new PlayingCard());
```

size of `playingCardList` would be 2